# Where to put sqlite .db files in iOS project?

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin

In Android project I put my .db files into my assets folder, but in iOS project where should I put them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your file anywhere you want, for instance in a folder called "Data".
Make sure the build action of the file is set to "BundleResource".

Use the following snippet to get the file's path :

```
var yourFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "yourfile.db");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite files I would never place them inside asset folders or the bundle directory. Sqlite files are best suited to be placed inside the personal directory, which is the directory for application data that is produced at runtime.

iOS is sandboxed by default, especially if you want to distribute on the AppStore (it's a requirement).

So in your case, create a helper function like this:

```
using System;

public class DbPathHelper {
     static string GetCommonSqlitePath() => System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mySqliteDb.db3");
}
```

Make sure as well to use a "db3" file extension for the Sqlite file, so you will use Sqlite3. Also use this nugget package if you need to manage your data:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/